# Create a project management app in Django - DAGs and Dependencies

Tags: python, sql, django, database, orm

I'm working in a Project management app. One of the points that the app needs is the possibility to create Tasks that have dependencies, i.e. Task 2 depends on Task 1, Task 3 depends on Task 2 and Task B, etc. This would generate a DAG (directed acyclic graph).

The problem is how to store this "graph" using the Django default ORM.

I've come with a solution that uses Many-to-Many relationship (Task with self) and a trigger to avoid creating cycles, but I still don't know how to implement some operations such as getting the whole graph from a single node.

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement it nicely? This would allow to perform an implementation of the Critical Path Method, for example.

**EDIT:**

Using the solution proposed by @Daniel I ended up with the function below. We can see that in order to get the whole graph multiple calls are being made to the database. This function also goes into an infinite loop during cycles.

```
def get_task_graph(task, visited_nodes = [], graph = {}):
    # Visited nodes are nodes that all parents were visited
    # print(task)

    
    
    previous_tasks = task.previous_tasks.all()

    
    still_have_unmarked_parents = set(previous_tasks).difference(set(visited_nodes))
    if still_have_unmarked_parents:
        print(f"Task {task} still have unmarked parents")
        
        for previous_task in still_have_unmarked_parents:
            

            visited_nodes, graph =  get_task_graph(previous_task, visited_nodes=visited_nodes, graph=graph)
    
    next_tasks = task.next_tasks.all()
 
    visited_nodes.append(task)
    print(f"Marking {task} as visited")
    graph[task] = []
    for next_task in next_tasks:
        if next_task not in graph[task]:
            graph[task].append(next_task)
    
        
        visited_nodes, graph = get_task_graph(next_task, visited_nodes=visited_nodes, graph=graph)
        print(f"\t Adding {next_task} to {task}")

    return visited_nodes, graph
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Original Answer: ManyToMany Relations

Let's create a simple `Task` model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(...)
   previous_tasks = models.ManyToMany('Task', ..., related_name='next_tasks')
```

Now let's create `taks_a` and `task_b` - `task_b` will depend on `task_a`:

```
# create task_a, task_b:
task_a = Task.objects.create(name='First Task')
task_b = Task.objects.create(name='Second task')

# add task_a as a dependency for task_b:
task_b.previous_tasks.add([task_a])
task_b.save()
```

Now we can access these tasks like so:

```
# get the tasks to do after task_a is complete:
task_a = Task.objects.get(id='<task-a-id>')
tasks_to_do_after_task_a = task_a.next_tasks.all() # returns a queryset with <task_b>

# get the tasks we need to complete before task_b:
task_b = Task.objects.get(id='<task-b-id>')
tasks_that_task_b_depends_on = task_b.previous_tasks.all() # returns a queryset with <task a>
```

Finally, let's assume `task_a` actually has a few different tasks that depend on it:

```
# iterate over all the tasks that depend on task a:
for tasks in task_a.next_tasks.all():

     # do some logic, i.e. find longest task:
     ...

# filter for a specific next_task on task_a:
some_task = task_a.next_tasks.filter(some_keyword='some_value')

# assume we have a duration time-field on tasks:      
next_longest_task = task_a.next_tasks.order_by('-duration')[0] # gets the next task with the longest duration
```

From there you can implement your path-finding logic / other algorithms as needed.

## EDIT: Recursively Accessing Fields

Okay - using the structure above we can define a function like so:

```
def get_task_list(task):

    # get the next_tasks queryset, it will either contain tasks or be an empty queryset:
    next_tasks = task.next_tasks.all()

    # check if the current task has any children:
    if next_tasks:

        # do some logic, check for longest tasks / add next tasks to a list
        ...

        # pass each next task back into the function:
        for next_task in next_tasks:
            return get_task_list(next_task)

    # exit if there are no more next tasks:
    else:

        # do some logic on exiting, calculate the time to complete all tasks:
        ...

        return <optional-content>
```

You can do some more research into recursive functions but this should get you started. You can get clever about looking up at previous tasks or down at next tasks in your function. You can also add this as a method to your `Task` model so that it can be called on a task instance.

Comment: So if I get a list of tasks for a project, I would loop through each one, get the next_tasks. For each next_task see predecessors to check its dependency and build the graph from there? 

Making sure that I mark visited nodes to avoid repetition (i.e. Task B appear on the list of the project but also as child of Task A, so it would be marked as visited because we already seen it). Is that right?

Comment: Your question is more about recursion than Django - you need to create a recursive function that looks for children and exists when no children are found - let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes, it would be easier with an example. I'm more of a beginner in this kind of things :(

Comment: See my edited answer - it should get you started on recursion with a Django instance. Otherwise you should look at some path-finding algorithms to solve your longest task list problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: Daniel, see the edit on my question. Your solution works very nicely when we want only to go one way in the graph. However, what is more desirable is to get the full graph from whatever node.

Comment: FYI you need to pass "symmetrical=False" with a M2M with "self" in order to utilize a related_name and not create a two way relationship with each new addition